# Partial derivates of Chapman Richards function

Tags: partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

I need to find the partial derivates of

$f(a,b,c) = a*(1-e^{-br})^c$

to build a Hessian used in a Gauss Newton non linear modelling. I think the partial derivate for parameter $a$ is quite trivial, but I would like to have confirmation:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a} = (1-e^{-br})^c$

For 
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial b}$ I struggle a lot more, as $b$ is contained in the brackets.

Partial derivate 
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial c}$ might be, but here I am struggling more than for $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}$:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial c} = log(1-e^{-br})*a*(1-e^{-br})^c $

Thanks for confirming or giving my the correct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=1-e^{-br}$. Then $$f(u)=au^c$$.

For shorthand (later in this post) let $$f_{a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$$
Consider then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{d u}{ db} \\
&= acu^{c-1} (re^{-br}) \\
&= arce^{-br}(1-e^{-br})^{c-1}
\end{align}
Your expression for $f_a$ is correct, and for $f_c$ conisder now the function $f(c)=au^c$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial c}ae^{c \ln u}\\
&= a\ln u e^{c \ln u} \\
&= a\ln(1-e^{-br})u^c \\
&= a\ln(1-e^{-br})(1-e^{-br})
\end{align}
Which agrees with your expression.